# Updating DataSource of DataGridView - old rows not removed

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, datagridview

I have an application with DataGridView. I use a SQLite database and set its table as a DataSource to my DataGridView: I'm getting a DataSet using SQLiteDataAdapter and setting it as a DataSource:

```
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;


grid.Columns["criteriaId"].DataPropertyName = "rowid";
grid.Columns["criteriaName"].DataPropertyName = "name";
grid.Columns["criteriaDesc"].DataPropertyName = "description";
grid.Columns["criteriaDirection"].DataPropertyName = "direction";
```

So far everything seems to be working as I want. But I want to update this DataSource, replacing all rows with other data from another dataset I got from another source. So I wrote:

```
var originalDs = grid.DataSource as DataView;
var originalTable = originalDs.Table;
originalTable.Rows.Clear();

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{   
    var newRow = originalTable.Rows.Add();

    foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        object item = row[column];
        var columnName = column.ColumnName;
        if (originalTable.Columns[columnName] != null)
        {
            newRow[columnName] = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Still, it works as expected, all rows in my DataGridView are replaced with new data. BUT. Now I am trying to update underlying database with these changes, so I am calling:

```
var cmdb = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdb.GetUpdateCommand();

var cm = (CurrencyManager)grid.BindingContext[grid.DataSource, grid.DataMember];
cm.EndCurrentEdit();

grid.EndEdit();
adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Where adapter is a SQLiteDataAdapter I used to read data from DB first. And here I'm stuck with a problem: instead of deleting all previous data and saving new rows to a database, all previous records are still in my database and all new rows from a new datasource are added. So it's just adding and not replacing rows. In a line above `adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);` when I debug I can see that ds.Tables[0] has only rows from a new source. So why aren't old rows deleted? What can I do to make it work?

Deletng rows from DB works when I delete rows in DataGridView manually using GUI and then save it all the same way to a database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I am missing it, but where do you copy the old PKs to the new rows? If you simply write rows with new keys why should old rows be updated? and which? Depending on the DBMS the Update should fail (my guess) or silently revert to an Insert..

Comment: Well, by replacing old rows I didn't mean replacing them one to one, like replacing 3 rows wit another 3 rows. I want to delete previous rows and insert new ones. While saving, new rows are getting new rowids. They got saved to a database but I don't know why old rows are not deleted.

Comment: Well then you need to explictily Delete the old ones.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I am calling `originalTable.Rows.Clear();` on my original DataSource, it makes rows empty but somehow they got not deleted from database. Should I do it another way then?

Comment: Clearing a DataTable's Rows has nothing to do with Deleting them from the Database. You need to issue an SQL Delete command.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but should it make it delete them from Database after an update? When I delete a row from a DataGridView using GUI and then use the same update function, then they got deleted. This is why I don't understand why such way of removing is not working.

Comment: Yes, I guess you will have to call the dataadpter's update method. But I'm not using SQLite so far, so I won't be much help with its interface objects. These differ somewhat between DBMSs. Do a search for 'deleting datagridviewrows from sqlite database'